# Making a multi-tenant model in Flutter using Firebase but authentication seems to be open

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The authentication seems to be open which makes it possible to sign in to some other tenant.
We are going by company wise database structure using cloud firestore in which every user is allocated to a particular company. While signing in there is a possibility the user can sign in to some other tenant which could lead us into a huge blunder for the company and for us.

We want each user to be specific to a particular company when they login to avoid confusion. We are  using 2FA authentication but that does not help in any way to avoid such issue of one tenant leading to some other tenant database. We do understand authentication and database are two different aspect how ever we want to authenticate a use to a particular tenant and sign in them into a particular company.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You provide few information, How to implement multi-tenant?

- To project level, with a main Firebase project and N projects one for each tenant
- To database level, with a single project (then a single Auth) and you manage tenants in Firestore

In the first case, tenant isolation is free you can use the main project to handle tenants and common information and specific tenant project to tenant-specific information. You need to replicate the login on each tenant.

In the second case, you need to work with custom claims on user and Firebase rules to manage collection access.

I hope it can be useful for you